# spring security endless redirecting to login page spring security 6

Tags: spring

After requesting the POST localhost:8000/api/user/login with JSON data

```
{
    "username": "TEST",
    "password" : "TEST2",
    "email": "tes23"
}
```

The responce is: Printing Error: Number of redirects hit maximum amount
One request respond to this into the console

`2023-06-14T17:05:36.247-04:00  WARN 27071 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' is not supported] 2023-06-14T17:05:36.261-04:00  WARN 27071 --- [nio-8000-exec-3] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' is not supported] 2023-06-14T17:05:36.263-04:00  WARN 27071 --- [nio-8000-exec-4] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' is not supported] 2023-06-14T17:05:36.265-04:00  WARN 27071 --- [nio-8000-exec-5] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' is not supported] 2023-06-14T17:05:36.266-04:00  WARN 27071 --- [nio-8000-exec-6] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' is not supported] 2023-06-14T17:05:36.268-04:00  WARN 27071 --- [nio-8000-exec-7] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' is not supported] 2023-06-14T17:05:36.270-04:00  WARN 27071 --- [nio-8000-exec-8] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' is not supported] 2023-06-14T17:05:36.271-04:00  WARN 27071 --- [nio-8000-exec-9] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' is not supported] 2023-06-14T17:05:36.273-04:00  WARN 27071 --- [io-8000-exec-10] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' is not supported] 2023-06-14T17:05:36.275-04:00  WARN 27071 --- [nio-8000-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' is not supported]`

Controller

```
    @PostMapping("/create")
    public ResponseEntity<String> createUser(@RequestBody CreateUserRequest createUserRequest) {
        String username = createUserRequest.getUsername();
        String password = createUserRequest.getPassword();

        userService.createUser(username, password, Collections.singleton("DEFAULT"));

        return ResponseEntity.ok("User created successfully");
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<String> login(@RequestBody LoginRequest loginRequest) {
        String username = loginRequest.getUsername();
        String password = loginRequest.getPassword();

        boolean isValidUser = userService.validateUser(username, password);

        if (isValidUser) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Login successful");
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body("Invalid credentials");
        }
    }
```

SecurityConfiguration

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {


    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/api/admin/**").hasRole(String.valueOf(PermissionLevel.ADMINISTRATOR))
                        .requestMatchers("/api/user/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin(form -> form
                        .loginPage("/api/user/login")
                        .permitAll()
                )

                .logout(logout -> logout
                        .logoutUrl("/logout")
                        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                )
                .sessionManagement(session -> session
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                ).csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);


        return httpSecurity.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

Gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}
```

I tried to request http://localhost/403 (which is not present in the application) and got Error: Number of redirects hit maximum amount. Any request including /api/admin, /api/test403, /403, returns the bunch of errors and endless redirecting into the login page

Comment: are you sure that you do `POST`  ? because  `Request method 'GET' is not supported` tell you that you do `GET` instead of `POST`